# Dual space operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $p,q\in(1,\infty)$ satisfy $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ and $a=(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty \in \ell_q.$ I want to prove that $\|f\|=\|a\|$, if
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \xi_k,$$
for $x=(\xi_k)_{k=1}^\infty\in \ell_p$ and $f\in \ell_p^*$ ($\ell_p^*$ is the dual space of $\ell_p$).

Using Hölder's inequality, we get
\begin{align*}
\|f\|&=\sup_{x\in B_{\ell_{p}}}|f(x)|\\
&=\sup_{x\in B_{\ell_{p}}}\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k \xi_k\right| \\
&\leqslant \sup_{x\in B_{\ell_{p}}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_k \xi_k |\\
&\leqslant \sup_{x\in B_{\ell_{p}}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_k|^q\right)^{1/q}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\xi_k|^p\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_k|^q\right)^{1/q}\\
&=\|a\|.
\end{align*}
Next, I need to show that $\|f\|\geqslant \|a\|$? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $\xi$ given by
\begin{align}
\xi_i = \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(a_i)|a_i|^{q-1}}{|| a||_q^{q-1}}.
\end{align}
Observe $\xi \in \ell^p$, since
\begin{align}
\left(\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{|a_i|^{p(q-1)}}{||a||_q^q}\right)^{1/p} = \left(\sum^\infty_{i=1} \frac{|a_i|^q}{||a||_q^q} \right)^{1/p} = \frac{||a||_q^{q/p}}{||a||_q^{q/p}}<\infty.
\end{align}
Moreover, we have that
\begin{align}
f(\xi) = \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{|a_i|^q}{||a||^{q-1}}=||a||_q.
\end{align}